# What is wrong in this php class

Tags: php, oop

I am newbie to the OOP concept of php.I have made a class like this

```
<?Php
  class ShopProductWriter {
    public function write( $shopProduct ) {
    $str = "{$shopProduct->title}: " .
            $shopProduct->getProducer() .
           " ({$shopProduct->price})\n";
    print $str;
    }
  }

  $product1 = new ShopProduct( "My Antonia", "Willa", "Cather", 5.99 );
  $writer = new ShopProductWriter();
  $writer->write( $product1 );
?>
```

Here I am getting the error like `Fatal error: Class 'ShopProduct' not found in line 11`actually I am doing this example from a tutorial.Can someone tell me where is the wrong part.I have made exact like the tutorial.

Comment: What the error says -- where have you defined `ShopProduct`? Are you missing an include?

Comment: @newuser where have you defined ShopProduct class.

Comment: It's likely that the tutorial is building up on a previous example and you're supposed to add this code to the previous code, not use it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you also need to define a ShopProduct Class like that:

```
class ShopProduct 
{
    public $title;
    public $price;        

    public function __construct( $title, $value1, $value2, $price)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->price= $price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create new instance of class  ShopProduct although you didn't define it. You declared only ShopProductWriter and not ShopProduct. That's why `$writer = new ShopProductWriter();` works and `$product1 = new ShopProduct( "My Antonia", "Willa", "Cather", 5.99 );` doesn't work.